# Spring 405 error for POST method

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to secure my website using Spring security following the guides on the web. I don't want my users to use my application through web browsers, so I disabled the csrf protection. The source code on the server side:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
implements ApplicationContextAware {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }

@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilde r authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
.withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMI N");
}
}

@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/course")
public class CourseController implements ApplicationContextAware{

@RequestMapping(value="/course", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Course> get(// The critirion used to find.
@RequestParam(value="what", required=true) String what,
@RequestParam(value="value", required=true) String value) {
//.....
}

@RequestMapping(value="/course", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public List<Course> upload(@RequestBody Course[] cs) {
}
}
```

I am using RestTemplate on the client side. The problem is that when I use POST method, I got warinning on the server side:
        o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

And on the client side, I got:
        Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed

It is odd I got this exception because I already have the POST method handled in the Controller. Currently, the system still works, but this issue bothers me.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: could it be that your upload-method is insufficiently annotated? you have a @ResponseBody annotation on the get-method which you don't have there.

Comment: could you please post your complete upload() method here.

Comment: For me, the error got solved when I called the right type of method (PUT instead of POST)

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I found what was wrong. Hope this helpful for someone else.
This mistake is quite stupid. The return value of upload() should use @ResponseBody, because I want to return the courses directly.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/course", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Course> upload(@RequestBody Course[] cs) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try with setting both methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/course", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST } produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Course> get(// The critirion used to find.
@RequestParam(value="what", required=true) String what,
@RequestParam(value="value", required=true) String value) {
//.....
}

@RequestMapping(value="/course", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST } , produces="application/json")
public List<Course> upload(@RequestBody Course[] cs) {
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` class may need to be extend.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It gives a ambiguous controller error. So guess have to try custom AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter now

Comment: For me, the error got solved when I called the right type of method (PUT instead of POST)